# AWS codepipeline for Next.js website on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next.js, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have Codepipeline working great to

1. Pull source files from Github
2. Build a working Next.js website on Codebuild and output to S3
3. According to Codedeploy, there is success when deploying the S3 file Elastic Beanstalk

However, I'm having issues once Elastic Beanstalk tries to run.

```
Oct 26 15:55:23 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Oct 26 15:55:23 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx web: requireStack: [ '/var/app/current/node_modules/.bin/next' ]
Oct 26 15:55:23 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx web: }
Oct 26 15:55:23 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx web: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Oct 26 15:55:23 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx web: npm ERR! errno 1
Oct 26 15:55:23 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx web: npm ERR! with-typescript@1.0.0 start: `next start`
Oct 26 15:55:23 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx web: npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

My start command is `next start`, but it appears that the node modules aren't there. When I unzip the output in S3 I see a full next.js build, so that part seems okay. I can't seem to find a solution to why it won't run on ELB - any idea where things are going wrong? Below is my buildspec.yml, for reference.

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    #If you use the Ubuntu standard image 2.0 or later, you must specify runtime-versions.
    #If you specify runtime-versions and use an image other than Ubuntu standard image 2.0, the build fails.
    runtime-versions:
       nodejs: 12
    commands:
       - yarn
  build:
    commands:
       - npx next build
artifacts:
  files:
     - '**/*'
```

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, everything was in place, but the "next" command was unrecognized. The solution was to use the absolute path on my start command: `node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start`.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use ```files:
     - '**/*'```? This will copy over the whole app including the node_modules folder. Maybe you should just copy the .next folder?

Answer (score -1):

Add `npm install next -g` in phases.index.commands, that will let container recognize `next`.

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    #If you use the Ubuntu standard image 2.0 or later, you must specify runtime-versions.
    #If you specify runtime-versions and use an image other than Ubuntu standard image 2.0, the build fails.
    runtime-versions:
       nodejs: 12
    commands:
       - yarn
       - npm install next -g
  build:
    commands:
       - npx next build
artifacts:
  files:
     - '**/*'
```

Comment: I'm not following completely. Does that go into the buildspec.yml?

Comment: commands:
   - yarn
   - npm install next -g


Yes, `npm install next -g` below yarn